# OpenStreetMap delete country data

Tags: openstreetmap

I have installed openstreetmap on my server, i have imported only my country on the first installation, but after a month i have added to the same map (postgresql database) another country using this command:

```
 osm2pgsql -a --slim -d osm_map -C 1600 --hstore -S openstreetmap-carto-2.10.0/openstreetmap-carto.style spain-latest.osm.bz2
```

But now i want the delete all spain data from the database.
Is that possible using an script? I couldn't found anything on the web.
I'm pretty sure that i have to delete planet_osm_lines, planet_osm_nodes, etc. But maybe there is a script for doing it.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a solution, i create my own script to delete nodes from database using a polygon.
The only table i have missed is planet_osm_rels that i've found this link: [relation in OSM](https://amisha2016.wordpress.com/tag/relation-in-osm/) thats explain how planet_osm_rels is related, but is an small table, and you need to parse the text from members extracting n and w to found the corresponding ids.

```
delete from planet_osm_line where osm_id in (select id from planet_osm_nodes WHERE st_contains(
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((110.59 -11.33484,110.59 -38.50,157 -38.50,157 -11.33484,110.59 -11.33484))',4326),
st_pointfromtext('POINT ('|| (lon / 10000000.0) || ' ' || (lat / 10000000.0) || ')',4326)))

delete from planet_osm_polygon where osm_id in (select id from planet_osm_nodes WHERE st_contains(
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((110.59 -11.33484,110.59 -38.50,157 -38.50,157 -11.33484,110.59 -11.33484))',4326),
st_pointfromtext('POINT ('|| (lon / 10000000.0) || ' ' || (lat / 10000000.0) || ')',4326)))

delete from planet_osm_point where osm_id in (select id from planet_osm_nodes WHERE st_contains(
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((110.59 -11.33484,110.59 -38.50,157 -38.50,157 -11.33484,110.59 -11.33484))',4326),
st_pointfromtext('POINT ('|| (lon / 10000000.0) || ' ' || (lat / 10000000.0) || ')',4326)))

delete from planet_osm_roads where osm_id in (select id from planet_osm_nodes WHERE st_contains(
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((110.59 -11.33484,110.59 -38.50,157 -38.50,157 -11.33484,110.59 -11.33484))',4326),
st_pointfromtext('POINT ('|| (lon / 10000000.0) || ' ' || (lat / 10000000.0) || ')',4326)))

delete from planet_osm_ways where id in (select w.id from planet_osm_nodes n INNER JOIN planet_osm_ways w ON n.id = ANY (w.nodes) WHERE st_contains(
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((110.59 -11.33484,110.59 -38.50,157 -38.50,157 -11.33484,110.59 -11.33484))',4326),
st_pointfromtext('POINT ('|| (n.lon / 10000000.0) || ' ' || (n.lat / 10000000.0) || ')',4326)))
```

And finally we delete nodes:

```
delete from planet_osm_nodes n where st_contains(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((110.59 -11.33484,110.59 -38.50,157 -38.50,157 -11.33484,110.59 -11.33484))',4326),
st_pointfromtext('POINT ('|| (n.lon / 10000000.0) || ' ' || (n.lat / 10000000.0) || ')',4326))
```